# How to import firebase functions with npm?

Tags: javascript, firebase

**Webpack is currently unable to build my project due to an error:**

```
The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
```

Imports that Webpack doesn't like most likely look like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-firestore.js";
import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { getStorage  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-storage.js";
import { onAuthStateChanged, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-auth.js";
```

**How can I import this with npm or any other webpack-friendly way?**

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible for you to just do `npm i firebase` and import those functions?

Also what framework are you using? There could be a firebase library tailored specifically for your framework, like Angular.